# How to extract table from weather underground

Tags: python, web-scraping

url: https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/KLGA/date/2020-5-5

```
url='https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/KLGA/date/2020-5-5'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is being rendered and I cant find anything referencing the data in XHR josn or in the html element. maybe get the data from an api somewhere wlse

Comment: spoke too soon! I did find an XHR, adding it as an answer

Comment: Hi, thanks all. I applied soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text) but cannot get the table information in soup. I do not know why. I am a beginner for HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an xhr to get the data you need if you're just looking to get temps this doesn't need any modification other than converting the unix timestamp to a human-readable:

```py
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KLGA:9:US/observations/historical.json?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&units=e&startDate=20200505&endDate=20200505'
json_response = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)

json_fields = [ # filters for fields in the json
    'valid_time_gmt',
    'temp'
]
root_node = 'observations'

temps = [{field: row[field] for field in json_fields}
         for row in json_response[root_node]]

print(json.dumps(temps, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "valid_time_gmt": 1588654260,
        "temp": 51
    },
    {
        "valid_time_gmt": 1588657860,
        "temp": 50
    },
    {
        "valid_time_gmt": 1588661460,
        "temp": 49
    },
    {
        "valid_time_gmt": 1588665060,
        "temp": 49
    },
    ...
]
```

You don't actually NEED to filter the fields but it makes it more manageable

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot.

Comment: I always check for json content when web scraping. In chrome press f12 (developer mode) and go to the Network tab, then refresh the page. Check all the items that come in under the XHR tab